# what‘s the difference for an instance of ModelForm between getting field values from argument data and directly from request.POST?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

here is my code:

```
from .forms import ImageCreateForm


@login_required
def image_create(request):
    """
    View for creating an Image using the JavaScript Bookmarklet.
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # form is sent
        # ########  here is my issue ####################
        form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.POST)
        # ########  end of  my issue ####################
        if form.is_valid():
            ......
            # redirect to new created item detail view
            return redirect(new_item.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        # build form with data provided by the bookmarklet via GET
        form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.GET)

    return render(request, 'images/image/create.html', {'section': 'images', 'form': form})
```

this block of code is from the book of Django by Example, but when I'm on official website of Django, I read that an instance of Modleform is created like this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms

The save()method

```
# Create a form instance from POST data.
>>> f = ArticleForm(request.POST)
```

so here is my question: what is the difference between the two ways of creating a form instance from POST data

Comment: Why should you think there is a difference? This is standard Python; the first positional argument to the form `__init__` function is `data`, so you can pass it positionally or via keyword.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first positional argument to the form __init__ function is data, so we can pass it positionally

```
f = ArticleForm(request.POST)
```

or via keyword

```
f = ArticleForm(data=request.POST)
```

Thank Daniel Roseman for telling me this.